# Environment.CurrentDirectory vs System.Reflection

Tags: .net, system.reflection

Out of the following methods to get the working directory of an executing assembly, is there a recommendation on which one is considered Best Practice?  I hear from my developers that Method 1 fails on Windows 7 SP1 64-bit *sometimes*, unless run with elevated permissions (**Run as Administrator**).  But Method 2 works all the time.  Is there a reason that the former would fail sometimes?

Method 1:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location())
```

Method 2:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Environment.CurrentDirectory` is the way to go as it is there for getting the working directory. Using reflection is also possibly slower.

BUT be careful: the two methods are NOT the same: Method A returns allways the directory where the assembly is stored in, where as `Environment.CurrentDirectory` gives you the current working directory which can change during the application lifetime, as `Environment.CurrentDirectory` can also be used to set the working directory and other method could also change it (e.g. file open/save dialogs).

Comment: Thanks! That's a pretty good caution (I just voted you up).  Is there a reason why it fails "sometimes" on Win 7 64-bit Sp1?

Comment: @RomulusParthus: I'm sorry I can't help you on that one - maybee it is the location where the assembly is stored, but thats only a wild guess...

Comment: In the absence of any further posts to this thread, I am marking this advice from chrfin as the answer.